# Error opening txt file on MacOSx

Tags: macos

I am getting this strange error on Mac OS X. When I am trying to open a text file using 'TextEdit' or 'TextWrangler' I am getting this message "Verifying filename.txt". This message pops up and then after a while whole system comes to halt. I have to forcefully shutdown the system. I was able to open these files previously with either of the two applications. I have OS X Mavericks (10.9).

Has anyone faced a situation like this? What can be the remedy?

Comment: Do you have a virus scanner of any kind installed? Can you look at the file content using Quicklook (press Space bar in Finder)? Does it happen with all text files? Can you create a new file in TextEdit, save it, then quit the application and open it on restart?

Comment: I do not have a virus scanner. I look at file content using quicklook. Yes it happens with all text files. Yes I can create a file in text edit and save it and then again reopen it with text edit.

Comment: Why am I getting this strange message "Verifying filename.txt". A small window pops up with this message and bar in it, which appears to be loading. But after a while everything halts.

Comment: Please post a screen capture of the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the screencap, it really sounds like a filesystem error to me, yeah I could be full of little red ants but the first thing I would do is open disk utility and do two things, repair permissions and verify the disk (you cant repair it, repair will be greyed out).

If permissions repair works you are golden, if the disk does not pass verification, boot into recovery mode (reboot holding COMMAND-R) and run disk utility and repair the disk.

If that doesn't fix it (EG Disk Utility returns an error message) it may be time for a third party repair tool like Diskwarrior or Drive Genius. If THAT fails then it's time to backup, reformat and reinstall the O/S and restore your Apps and files... You **do** have a backup, don't you?